# Close form fomula for Narayana's cows sequence

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am using Narayana’s cows sequence [OEIS A000930](http://oeis.org/A000930) in a paper I am about to submit to a conference. The link gives a closed form, however, I am not sure if I can cite the link in the paper because some program committee members will (most likely) complain about it.

The sequence is
$g(n) = g(n-3) + g(n-1)$, where $g(0)=g(1)=g(2)=1$.
The link says that $g(n)=\left\lfloor dc^n+\frac12\right\rfloor$, where $d \approx 0.611$ and $c\approx 1.466$.

I was wondering if there is a paper that contains/proves this closed form formula.
(I looked through several papers but I was not able to find it.)

Comment: Citing OEIS is common practice. Why do you think this would not be acceptable? There are references in the OEIS page you link to where the formula may be proved.

Comment: If you are looking at `a(n) = floor(d*c^n + 1/2) where c is the real root of x^3-x^2-1 and d is the real root of 31*x^3-31*x^2+9*x-1 (c = 1.465571... = A092526 and d = 0.611491991950812...). - Benoit Cloitre, Nov 30 2002` then you can certainly [reference  OEIS](http://oeis.org/wiki/Welcome#Referencing_the_OEIS) and mention his name ([he is a serious researcher](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Benoit-Cloitre))

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I was under the impression that the cited material are supposed to be from peer reviewed resources. I will try to add it, and see if they complain or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADDED next morning:  took forever, I finally confirmed that my $A$  satisfies $31A^4 - 22 A^2 + 8A - 1$  which reduces,  eventually
$$  31 A^3 - 31 A^2 + 9A - 1 = 0$$
Meanwhile, the dependence is $A = \frac{\alpha^3}{\alpha^3 + 2}$  with
$$ \alpha \approx 1.465571231876768026656731225 $$
$$  A \approx 0.6114919919508125184143170109 $$
An intermediate step was confirming that $\alpha^{12}-3\alpha^9 - \alpha^6 + 2 \alpha^3 - 1=0.$  From

$$  x^{12}  - 3 x^9 - x^6 + 2 x^3 - 1 = $$ $$ (x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x^3-x^2-1)(x^6+x^5+x^4-2x^3-x^2+1) $$

Then using $\alpha^3 = \frac{2A}{1-A}$  That is, $\delta = \alpha^3$  is a root of $\delta^4 - 3 \delta^3 - \delta^2 + 2 \delta  - 1 = (\delta+1)(\delta^3-4\delta^2 + 3 \delta -1)   $

ORIGINAL:the set of sequences $x_n$   with $ x_{n+3}  - x_{n+2} - x_n = 0$ is a vector space over the complexes.  A basis is
$$   \alpha^n \; \; , \; \;  \beta^n \; \; , \; \;  \bar{\beta}^n \; \; , \; \; $$
where
$ \alpha \approx  1.465571231876768026656731225 $  and
$ \beta \approx   -0.2327856159383840133283656126 + 0.7925519925154478483258983007i$

Note that $\beta$ and $\bar{\beta}$ have norm smaller than $1,$  so that $\beta^n$ and $\bar{\beta}^n$  approach $0$  fairly quickly.

I see, you are calling my $\alpha = C$

Any complex series can be written using the basis. If all elements of the sequence are real, the coefficients come out
$$  x_n = A  \alpha^n + B \beta^n + \bar{B} \bar{\beta}^n $$

Once more, you have my $A = d.$   From the comment about the norms going to zero, we know that  ( because your sequence is always integers) $x_n$  really is the closest integer to $A  \alpha^n.$   Rounding a positive real $t$ to the nearest integer can be done with $ \left\lfloor t + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor $

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you please explain how to find $A$ as well. I know that it is the real root of $31\cdot x^3-31\cdot x^2+9\cdot x-1$ but I am not sure how to derive that.

Comment: In the paper by Xin Lin (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348652924_On_the_Recurrence_Properties_of_Narayana%27s_Cows_Sequence), they say $A= \frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^3+2}=0.417\dots$ but this does not match the answer that I found at other places which is $A\approx 0.61$.

Comment: @KokoNanahji  Lin's $A,B,C$  must be a little different because  he says $G_0 = 0$  then $G_1=G_2=G_3 = 1$  You have $g_0=g_1=g_2 =1$  and I guess $g_{-1} = 0$  Lin would get your desired numbers if  the formulas just after (4) were changed to $A+B+C=1$

Comment: @KokoNanahji  correcting Lin gives $A= \frac{\alpha^3}{\alpha^3 + 2} = \alpha \cdot  \frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^3 + 2}$

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want the exact formulae

$$c_1=\frac{1}{3} \left(1+2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{29}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$

and

$$d_1=\frac 13 \Bigg[1+\frac{4}{\sqrt{31}}\cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{31}}{2}\right)\right) \Bigg]$$